# How do I add transitions on JSX that is rendered from a mapped array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions

I have an array of items which I map in my UI:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7... n]
```

Say I want to map each item as a `JSX` paragraph BUT, I want to be able to change the order of each element within the array by calling a function `swap` which changes the value of `arr` (assume that `arr` is stored in a `redux slice` and automatically updates after calling function `swap`.

For example, if I call the function `swap(3, "up")`, then the item `3` will be swapped with the item `2` and the result will be: `[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7... n]`. Conversely, if I swap the other direction - `down`, the item will swap with its successor.

I also have a `delete` function which will remove the item altogether and all the items after it will get bumped up by one space: `delete(4)` will result in `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7...n]`.

This logic is done, it all works and I have observed that the changes apply perfectly in the UI. The problem is that I need to somehow inform the user that this happened. For example, a transition or animation so that the action is not instant.

Here is what I have written:

```
const lectures = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.course.lectures) 
/* lectures always is sorted by its positional index which changes with swap 
(swapping two elements) and delete (deletes current and bumps up all its 
successors) */ 

const delete = (lecture) => { 
    /* a dispatch to an action that will result in deleting an item from the lectures array */
}

const swap = (lecture, direction) => { 
    /* a dispatch to an action that will result in swapping the given lecture with its pred/succ depending on the direction. */
}

return (
  <div>
    {
      lectures.map(lect => (
        <span>
            <h3>{lect.position_index}</h3>
            <p>{lect.title}</p>
            <button onClick={e => swap(lect, "up")}>UP</button>
            <button onClick={e => swap(lect, "down")}>DOWN</button>
            <button onClick={e => delete(lect)}>DELETE</button>
        </span>
      )
    }
  </div>
)
```

The changes apply but they are instantaneous. I want to add a transition of some sort - 200 or 300 milliseconds transition disappearing effect on delete and tbh anything for the swapping it doesn't matter as long as the user knows that it happens.
I dont want the users to end up deleting the wrong lecture because they thought that their delete didn't take effect.

I apologize for any misused terminology.

Here is the requested sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-gianmarco-xj2ppv?file=/src/features/posts/PostsList.js

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience doing this, but I do know what it is called. This is commonly called a FLIP animation. I searched that and found [this lib](https://github.com/aholachek/react-flip-toolkit) You can take a look at this if you want. (I heard about FLIP because it is baked into sveltejs, and I have read about their implementation)

Comment: I'll vote to close this since it looks like you're looking for recommendation on libraries. I will however suggest [AutoAnimate](https://auto-animate.formkit.com/) and [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/)

Comment: @Zachiah Thanks I will check it out. This actually helps helps me a lot, now I know what to look for online.

Comment: @RubenSmn Im not looking for recommendation I am looking for a solution and that may not neciserally derive from a library - a custom solution is always preferable because it reduces package size.

Comment: @Dimitar makes sense. Well [here](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/) is an article about how flip works if you're interested

Comment: Do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the base code, e.g. the rendering of the array and state/actions to swap state, that we could work from live? (*Saves us from standing this part up and possibly missing something*)

Comment: @DrewReese Sure thing, I will edit the post right away. Please note, I did not integrate it with an external API or create a mock API as it is not essential for this purpose, I just want to add some sort of a transition after the `pos_idx` changes in order to notify the user that they successfully moved or deleted a post.

Comment: That's fine. I don't see how any external data would be relevant to "animating" some "UI" that is rendered from an array anyway.

Comment: Has anyone had a chance to take a look at the provided sandbox and find a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out that I cannot solve this with any libraries or tools - I had to implement my own solution as I expected.

The way I did this is by having two states in the parent component where I render my lectures - `deleting` and `swapping`:

```
const [deleting, setDeleting] = useState<number | null>(null)
const [swapping, setSwapping] = useState<number | null>(null)
```

Whenever I run a `delete` or `swap` I basically set these states with the `lecture id` and put the `dispatch` in a `timeout`:

```
const delete = lecture => {
    setDeleting(lectute.id)
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(deleteLecture(lecture))
    }, 500)
} // Same code for the Swap function with a different dispatch more or less
```

In my render I have basically the same code with a minor detail - conditioanl class name for when it is being deleted:

```
<div>
  {
    lectures.map(lect => (
      <span className={`transition ${deleting === lect.id ? "delete" : ""} ${swapping === lect.id ? "swap" : ""}`}>
        <h3>{lect.position_index}</h3>
        <p>{lect.title}</p>
        <button onClick={e => swap(lect, "up")}>UP</button>
        <button onClick={e => swap(lect, "down")}>DOWN</button>
        <button onClick={e => delete(lect)}>DELETE</button>
      </span>
    )
  }
</div>
```

Finally, I have two `useEffects` which listen on changes to `deleting` and `swapping` states and update their state properly:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (deleting === null) return
    setTimeout(() => setDeleting(null), 2000)
}, [deleting])

useEffect(() => {
    if (swapping === null) return
    setTimeout(() => setSwapping(null), 2000)
}, [swapping])
```

I made it 2000ms assuming that it will not take more than 1500ms for the dispatch to resolve which currently takes up to 800ms on slow internet in production environment under stress conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing css styles with useState, not sure if it's 100% what you're looking for, but it definitely works.